# Сопоставление url маршруту

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, route

Доброгов времени суток! Подскажите пожалуйста вот что. Имеется веб приложение на asp.net mvc. Допустим у меня есть некий url. Можно ли как-то узнать, корректен ли этот урл для данного приложения? То есть существует ли какое-то действие у какого то контроллера которое бы соответствовало этому урлу, либо зарегистрирован какой-то маршрут в таблице маршрутов который способен этот урл сопоставить с каким-то контроллером и действием?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если вы подходите с точки зрения пользователя, проверить корректность url можно только отправив запрос по этому url и получив ответ в виде веб-страницы или в виде статусного кода 404, 403 и т.д
Если вы подходите с точки зрения программиста, то надо просто посмотреть на имеющиеся маршруты и сопоставить их с данным url. Если шаблон маршрута соответствует url, и в приложении есть ресурсы - контроллер и методы, которые могут обработать данный запрос, то все нормально.